# Gulp takes over 10 mins to start

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I'm setting up a dev environment at work, behind the usual firewalls etc.

I needed to set ssl-strict to false to install using npm.

When I run gulp, it appears to hang. But if I wait long enough (Over 10 mins) gulp does actually eventually start and run the 'Hello World' console.log test code in my gulpfile.js

That seems unbelievably long. What gives? is there sometning thatcould be slowing gulp down? or is something being blocked? as far as I'm aware I can't log gulp to bugfix and raise with IT.

Comment: Does running anything else from node start up slowly (e.g. just a simple nodejs hello world)?

Comment: Not that I've encountered so far. I set up a simple app.js file that starts up localhost on 127.0.0.1:3000 and after running node app.js it fires up straight away and I can access my hello world welcome page.